# Is it possible to group by and get counts within a json_agg?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

TL;DR: Is there a way to use json_agg to get the counts for each distinct value from a join table?

I have data in the following format in a Postgres DB:

`people`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dan |
| 2 | Fred |
| 3 | Bob |

`engagements`

| id | title | engagement_types_id | people_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | meeting1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | meeting2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | meeting3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | meeting4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | meeting5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | meeting6 | 3 | 3 |

`engagement_types`

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

And I'm trying to write a single query that gets the number of engagement types by people and the total number of overall engagements.

So far, I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  people.id,
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS "total",
  json_agg(distinct engagement_types.id)    
FROM people
INNER JOIN engagements on engagements.people_id = people.id
INNER JOIN engagement_types on engagement_types.id = engagements.engagement_types_id
GROUP BY people.id
```

Which I'm able to use to get the distinct types, but not the counts. I'm struggling to wrap my head around `jsonb_build_object` and `json_agg`. **Is there a way to use json_agg to get the counts for each distinct engagement_types.id?**

I'm trying to get the data in the following format:

| people_id | total | engagements_by_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | [{"id": "1", "count": 2}, {"id": "2", "count": 1}] |
| 2 | 3 | [{"id": "1", "count": 1}, {"id": "2", "count": 2}] |
| 3 | 4 | [{"id": "1", "count": 3}, {"id": "2", "count": 3}] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your query I would first aggregate engagement_types.id-s into an array per people.id then use the result as a CTE and reshape the `engagement_types_ids` array into your JSONB format. Please note that `engagement_types_ids` array may/will have repeating elements. Hence the relatively complicated conversion of the array into JSON.

```sql
with t as
(
SELECT 
 people.id,
 COUNT(*) "total",
 array_agg(engagement_types.id) engagement_types_ids
FROM people
INNER JOIN engagements on engagements.people_id = people.id
INNER JOIN engagement_types on engagement_types.id = engagements.engagement_types_id
GROUP BY people.id
)
select id, "total",
 (
   select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', i, 'count', cnt)) 
   from 
   (
    select i, count(*) cnt from unnest(engagement_types_ids) i group by i
   ) t
 ) engagements_by_type
from t;
```

**Edit**
If you think that the case is generic enough then it may make sense to create a reusable function that reshapes an array into the above JSON format.

```sql
create or replace function arrray_element_groups(arr anyarray)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as
$$
 select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', i, 'count', cnt)) 
 from (select i, count(*) cnt from unnest(arr) i group by i) t;
$$;
```

Then the query becomes much simpler and cleaner.

```sql
SELECT 
 people.id,
 COUNT(*) "total",
 arrray_element_groups(array_agg(engagement_types.id)) engagements_by_type
FROM people
INNER JOIN engagements on engagements.people_id = people.id
INNER JOIN engagement_types on engagement_types.id = engagements.engagement_types_id
GROUP BY people.id
```

Alternatively - aggregate first by `people.id, engagement_types.id` and then by `people.id` only and use `jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(...))`

```sql
with t as
(
SELECT 
 people.id people_id, engagement_types.id types_id, count(*) cnt 
FROM people
INNER JOIN engagements on engagements.people_id = people.id
INNER JOIN engagement_types on engagement_types.id = engagements.engagement_types_id
GROUP BY people.id, engagement_types.id
)
select people_id, sum(cnt) total, 
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', types_id, 'count', cnt)) engagements_by_type
from t
group by people_id;
```